# Wigner distribution harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, harmonic-oscillator, wigner-transform

I am interested in the Wigner distribution of a quantum harmonic oscillator
\begin{equation*}
W_n(q,p) = \int_{\mathbb R} \mathrm d x e^{ipx}\;\psi_n(q-x/2)\psi_n(q+x/2)
\end{equation*}
with wavefunction
\begin{equation*}
\psi_n(x) = \frac{\omega^{1/4}}{(2^n n!\sqrt{\pi})^{1/2}}H_n(\sqrt\omega x)e^{-\omega x^2/2} 
\end{equation*}
$\omega$ being the frequency of the oscillator and $H_n(x)$ the $n-$th Hermite polynomial. It is possible to find a closed expression for $W(q,p)$? If so, how? I tried to take advantage of the orthogonality relations of the Hermite polynomials, but I find them hardly applicable due to the shift in the arguments and the complex phase.

Comment: No, you need to exploit convolutions of Hermites closing into [Laguerres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-space_formulation#Simple_harmonic_oscillator). Groenewold  did, in his 1946 thesis paper which launched the field!

Comment: I see, I found the formal expression of the solution in terms of Laguerre polynomials in the book of Schleich, 'Quantum Optics in Phase Space', par 4.1.3.

Comment: In [our book](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/aaa.pdf), we solve for it directly in phase space, without the benefit of the pointless/useless Schroedinger eqn solutions.